# How to know when an input field is focused from a QML Webview in Qt5

Tags: qml, qt5, qtwebkit

I'm working on an UI in QML for an embedded linux (for now raspberry pi/raspbian, but the HW will change pretty soon). I'm using Qt 5.0.2

I integrated a QWebKit browser using the QML WebView.

I want to be able to know when an input field is focused, I found some solutions using JS (using addJavaScriptObject or evaluateJavaScript) but all of them are working for Qt4.7/4.8 and Qt5 seems to have drastically cut the number of usable methods for the QML WebView.

Do you know a way to get this information? can we do it directly in the QML files?

Thx,
Arthur

Comment: are you talking about the input field in the browser (to take url input) or the imput fields in web pages (login etc) ?

Comment: input fields in web pages ( login, search fields, etc)